# Некорректное отображение векторов в Windows

Tags: windows

На сайтах, таких как Яндекс, Вконтакте некорректно отображаются логотипы, формы поиска, некоторые кнопки (Вместо плавных и закругленных они угловатые все). Пример того, как у меня отображается логотип Яндекса прилагаю. Так же эти артефакты наблюдаются в различных программах, например PowerPoint. Если на шаблоне нарисован круг, то при выборе этого шаблона на слайде вместо круга будет какой то многоугольник.

[image: Отображение логотипа Яндекс у меня в браузере]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отображаются логотипы ГДЕ? Ну кроме паверпоинта. Какая версия винды? Через какой браузер смотришь? Какая версия паверпоинта?

Comment: На сайтах различных. Версия винды 10. Браузер пробовал и Edge и Firefox. Паверпойт последний.

Comment: `ff` 69? А в хроме чё?

Comment: Что значит 69? Хром скачал - там тоже самое...

Comment: 69 - текущая мажорная на данный момент версия фокса.

Comment: Стоп. Если в браузерах у тебя такая шляпа - значит чё-то не то с ОС или дровами. Потому что лично у меня всё ок и у остальных тоже. Создай нового пользователя в винде и попробуй оттуда посмотреть.

Comment: Проверил на новом пользователе - всё тоже самое. Браузер Microsoft EDGE. Честно говоря сомневаюсь, что проблема в браузерах. Потому что по всей системе если есть такие изображения - наблюдаются такие косяки. Что делать - ума не приложу...

Comment: Т.е. не только в браузерах так плывёт, но ещё и в системе?